# Converting a LP into standard form

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to convert this LP into standard form and I am stuck on the part with $-1\leq x_1\leq 4$. I am unsure how to turn this into variables that are all greater than 0.

$\begin{array}{l@{}l}\text{minimize} & 4x_1+x_2+ 5x_3\\
    \text{subject to}& x_1+x_3 \geq 10 \\
    &2x_1+x_2+3x_3 \geq 15 \\
    &-1 \leq x_1 \le 4, x_2 \leq 0, x_3 \geq 0 \\
\end{array}$

My approach so far:

Let $x_2'=-x_2$

$\begin{array}{l@{}l}\text{maximize} & -4x_1+x_2'- 5x_3\\
    \text{subject to}& -x_1-x_3 \leq -10 \\
    &-2x_1+x_2'-3x_3 \leq -15 \\
    &-1 \leq x_1 \le 4,~x_2',~x_3 \geq 0 \\
\end{array}$

but then I don't know what to do with the $-1\leq x_1\leq 4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $x_1'=x_1+1\in[0,5]$ to get
$$\begin{array}{l@{}l}\text{maximize} &Z-\color{red}4=-4x_1'+x_2'- 5x_3\\
    \text{subject to}& -x_1'-x_3 \leq -11 \\
    &-2x_1'+x_2'-3x_3 \leq -17 \\
    &x_1' \le 5\\
    &x_{1,2}',~x_3 \geq 0 \\
\end{array}$$and note that $Z$ is maximized iff $Z-4$ is maximized.